# How to hanndle Unicode Character (U+200E) in azure logic app

Tags: azure, sharepoint, unicode, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have a problem with recognizing and converting Unicode Character (U+200E).

A brief description of the flow:

- I take the list from sharepoint
- I take the list from sql
- I instantiate a variable
- I take the values from SQL and store them for the conditions to be checked in the variable.

  [image]
- I check if the item from sharepoint list (Get Items) is already in sql (our previously initialized variable)

*code of condition: contains(variables('IMO'),int(items('For_each')?['IMO']))is equal to true*

[image]

Result:[image]

[image]In general, for 99% of records this code works because there are no invisible characters. I wondered for a long time why this one record does not work  in condition. When I exported this column I noticed that one record looks like this:

[image]

The field on sharepoint from which we take data is a text field. It contains numeric values but that is not important.

In sharepoint list, this record looks normal.

[image]

In get items output too:

[image]

And my question, is there an easy way to remove the unicode character so that you can fully use the extracted value without worries?

I'm trying to get around the removal of special characters somehow, so that in the future there will be no such errors. I expect someone has a proven method on how to do this.

Comment: That’s a lot of looping and although beside the point, you should look at using the **Advanced Data Operations** connector. There’s an *Expert* function that could help you perform the comparison AND remove the special characters all at the same time. It could be done in a single step. I know the guy at the company who created it. They’re very willing to help, you could email him both datasets and they could whip up an example for you.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, it was working fine. However, one way to solve this is to use `replace` function.

```
replace(items('For_each')?['sample']['<Path_To_Your_Value>'],'[U+200E]','')
```

or

```
replace(items('For_each')?['sample']['<Path_To_Your_Value>'],'\u200E','')
```

[image]

[image]

Another way you can try is, instead of converting the value to int, you can iterate through SQL list, in each iteration convert the current item to string and then use contains.